# jQuery Select nested in DataList tag - can't get the selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, autocomplete

I'm tring to implement an AutoComplete feature for an Input tag.

When I start typing, I get the dropdown, then I select one of the items.
When I'm trying to reach the selected item, I just get the 1st option from the options list instead of the one I chose.

This is what it looks like:

```
<input id="chosenTxt" list="someList">
  <datalist id="someList">
    <select id="selectList">
       <option value="First" label="one" />
       <option value="Second" label="two" />
       <option value="Third" label="three" />
    </select>
  </datalist>
</input>
```

Then for example I choose "Second" and use

```
$("#selectList option:selected").attr("label")
```

I get "one".

FYI : I know this is built in jQuery UI, but I don't wanna use it.

Comment: if you dont use jqueryUI's autocomplete wich autocomplete do you use?

Comment: One that I've already implemented

Comment: Wich one, because then we know how to answer your question, or can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Basically, I have a list of all the items that is created on page load, then I add a function to KeyUp which takes the current input value, filters the list to only choose items containing the subtext, and dynamically generate the <option> tags .

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for the `input` event on the input element and iterate over
the options, checking if the input `value` is equal to the `value` of one of the options.

You can access the options of the datalist element from the `options` property on the datalist.

Here is an example.

```js
$('#chosenTxt').on('input', function() {
  $that = $(this);
  $.each($('#someList')[0].options, function(idx, opt) {
    if($that.val() == opt.value) {
      console.log(opt.label)
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="chosenTxt" list="someList">
<datalist id="someList">
<select id="selectList">
  <option value="First" label="one" />
  <option value="Second" label="two" />
  <option value="Third" label="three" />
</select>
</datalist>
```

Comment: That won't work. If I have 2 same values, but different labels, I'll get the 1st every time